# iPad simulator (5.1) shows black screen upon launch

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am currently making an iPhone app. Everything works fine on the iPhone, no errors whatsoever. But as soon as I try to launch it with the iPad simulator, it shows a black screen with the x2/x1 in the right hand corner. The problem is that the app got rejected by Apple because of this. I am kind of stuck here, so if anyone could help me/guide me in the right direction, I would be very grateful!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using any device specific code like: `[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post how you are displaying your views.

Comment: Hello there! Thanks for the quick replies. Chris - I don't think I am, it's very simple coding and I am mainly using storyboards. But I will definatly check that in an hour or two. htinlinn - I am not very advance in my coding. I am mainly using storyboards, and I do not know much about cocoa-touch etc. That's the most detailed I can give, unless you direct me to the files that I would look into.

Comment: Is the project build set as universal? Make sure it's set to iPhone

Comment: The project is set as universal. I have no idea why this is happening, and it is really frustrating as I have gotten denied twice.

Comment: Put some break points in the viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear methods and have a look at where the frames of the views are. You may have somehow modified them and they aren't where you expect them to be. I have had problems similar to this, and that how I ended up discovering the root cause.